# Grouped UITableView - allowing multiple selections and single selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` that gets its data from a `NSArray`. The array contains model objects. I've split the `UITableView` up into sections. Now I'm trying to allow some sections to be multi-selectable and others to be only single selectable. My model object has a property that I use to determine if I need multi-selection or single selection. I'm almost there - I have managed to get multi-selection and single selection working in the correct sections. Here is the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    BBFilterProductAttribute *productAttribute = self.productAttributes[indexPath.section];

    if ([productAttribute.filterType isEqualToString:@"MULTI_SELECT_LIST"]) {
        if (productAttribute.option[indexPath.row]) {
            [self.selectedRows addObject:indexPath];
        }
        else {
            [self.selectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
        }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

To solve the reuse problem, when some cells have a check mark, even if they aren't selected I do this in my `cellForForAtIndexPath:` method:

```
if([self.selectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

//For single selection 
else if (self.selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row &&
         self.selectedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

My selections per section are working as they should. Each section allows multi-selection or single selection - depending on the `if` statement in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

The problem is:

If I select a row in section 2, let's say it's single selection, and then I select a row in section 3, also single selection, the check mark moves from section 2 to section 3.

I need section 2 and 3 to remain single selection - but allow both to have a row selected at the same time. So it should look like this:

- Section 1: (Multi selection): All rows selected
- Section 2: (Single selection): One row selected
- Section 3: (Single selection): One row selected

Instead of this, when I select a row from section 2, it looks like this:

- Section 1: (Multi selection): All rows selected
- Section 2: (Single selection: Previous selection removed
- Section 3: (Single Selection): One row selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    BBFilterProductAttribute *productAttribute = self.productAttributes[indexPath.section];

    if ([productAttribute.filterType isEqualToString:@"MULTI_SELECT_LIST"])
    {
        if (productAttribute.option[indexPath.row])
        {
            [self.selectedRows addObject:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {
           [self.selectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Section is SINGLE_SELECTION
        //Checking self.selectedRows have element with this section, i.e. any row from this section already selected or not
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicatewithFormat:@"section = %d", indexPath.section];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [self.selectedRows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        if ([filteredArray count] > 0)
        {
            //A row from this section selected previously, so remove that row
            [self.selectedRows removeObject:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        }

        //Add current selected row to selected array
        [self.selectedRows addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];    
}
```

Comment: Dude you rock! Perfect. It seems I need to do some more studying on NSPredicate. Would never have even thought of it!  :)